# Unable to access wikipedia API due to SSL-certificate error

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, python-requests

```
import requests

spiders = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php')
print(spiders)
```

With above code I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 554, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 750, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 252, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 305, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 376, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)

  File "C:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 983, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 628, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)
```

Using a certificate I still get an error:

```
import requests

spiders = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',cert = 'c:\python\lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem',verify = True)
print(spiders)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Files/3.py", line 3, in <module>
    spiders = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',cert = 'c:\python\lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem',verify = True)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 67, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 53, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:2824)
```

Even when I have followed some tutorial verbatim I have encountered this issue when the instructor would have access w/o issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: Specifying a certificate with `cert=` doesn't have anything to do with verifying the server certificate.  This allows you to *present* an SSL certificate to the remote server for authentication purposes.

Answer (score 0):

u can ignore SSL like this:

```
import requests

spiders = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',verify = False)
print(spiders)
```

other solution:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
rq = Request('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php')
response = urlopen(rq).read()
```

Comment: That worked.  But I don't understand why the error appeared for Requests but not urllib.request.  Is urllib3 broken for Python 3.5?

Comment: im still using python 3,2 (and 2.6), and urllib +urllib2  so for me its hard detect why is urllib3 so "sensitive"

Comment: You will be getting warnings from Requests if you do verify=False. To disable the warnings: requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()